# How to make REST api calls that needs auth_token?

Tags: django, rest, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm working on a Django-REST application that contains APIs that work with login mechanism.

I'm able to create API endpoints for login and logouts.

Login takes username, password and returns auth_token which is around 30 characters.

Logout takes auth_token and destroys it.

In between these login and logouts, there are few API calls that make use of auth_token.

How is it generally implemented ? How are the requests made with auth_token in general?

Where are those tokens stored? How do the backend validates it?

Can someone please explain me how it is done basically?

Comment: Presumably you've had a read of https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Answer (score 0):

store the token in browser storage. and remove the token form browser storage on logout logic. 
make sure you drf setting DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES list contain TokenAuthentication class before SessionAuthentication , rest_framework.authtoken in you setting install app.

for any api call just attach the token like (Token your_toke) I mean "Toke" then space the your token and attach it to your request authentication header of the ajax request